# What is the best way to copy a StringBuilder?

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

What is the best way (performance wise) to instantiate a new `StringBuilder` from another one? (Copy-Ctor).

I don't want to pass via an immutable string as the underline data is very big.

so the below is valid, but not wanted.

```
StringBuilder newSB = new StringBuilder(oldSB.ToString());
```

I want something like

```
StringBuilder newSB = new StringBuilder(oldSB);
```

But this is not supported.

Comment: With the aim of doing what?

Comment: The problem is that strings are immutable by nature. It seems that you want to kind of "share" the substring between two strings and it's quite big but in reality if those two string builders are supposed to produce two different strings (even if one is the subset of the other) than I am afraid it's impossible to accomplish what you want to do.

Comment: I think the OP wants to copy the contents of one StringBuilder's internal `Char[]` buffers to another without using a `String` as an intermediary.

Comment: @CaiusJard: return the constructed string from an object to the caller without passing via string... (the caller will then do what ever needed with the string... mainly but not limited to a "ToString()" operation....)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There’s [an overload of `Append`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.append?view=net-5.0#System_Text_StringBuilder_Append_System_Text_StringBuilder_) for other `StringBuilder` instances:

```
var newSB = new StringBuilder(oldSB.Length);
newSB.Append(oldSB);
```

Comment: @MitchWheat Good idea, and personally I'd also round-up `oldSB.Length` to the next nearest power-of-2 if more text is to be appended to it.

Comment: Note that this is only available for .net Core 2.1 or later.